# tensorflow2.1でGPUが遅い、使用率が低い

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

pythonでpygameを使った自作のゲームをGPUを搭載したwindowsで学習させているのですが、思ったほど速度がでなく疑問に思い、タスクマネージャーでGPUの使用率を見ると、終始3~5%ほどでちゃんと使われているのかがわかりません。

GPU自体良いものを使用していないので、そこまでの速度は期待していませんが、GPUが正常に使用されているのかが確認したいです。
また、学習中のメモリがタスクマネージャーで確認した所、90%を余裕で上回ります。（クラッシュせずに最後まで学習はできますが。）

学習環境はpython3でtensorflowの中にあるkerasとKeras-rl2を使い、DQNを実行しています。
学習のモデルは、deepmindのAtariのCNNを参考にしたので、それほど深いものではないです。
以下実行環境です。

------環境------
windows10
Intel Core i7
RAM 16GB
NVIDIA GeForce GTX1050TI
CUDA 10.1
cudnn 7.6.5

Python 3.7.6
tensorflow 2.1.0
Keras-rl2 1.0.4
------以上------

このGPUは正常に使われているか確認する方法はありますか
また、使用率が低いのは正常ですか
もし、GPUの性能を制限している等の設定がある場合、それの解除方法が知りたいです

お願いいたします

Comment: タスクマネージャのCPUとディスクの負荷は問題ありませんか？（GPU以外に原因がある可能性をつぶしたい）

Comment: CPUは10〜20%ほどで、ディスクは0〜1%です。

Comment: メモリ不足でページングが多発しているわけではなさそうですね。

Answer (score 0):

> GPUの使用率を見ると、終始3~5%ほど

明らかに学習用としては、使用されていないですね。
そもそもtensorflowがGPUを認識しているか確認していないですよね。

Answer (score 0):

タスクマネージャーではGPUの正確な状態がわからないかもしれません。
[ELSA System Graph](http://www.elsa-jp.co.jp/products/products-top/graphicsboard/geforce/gpu_manager/elsa_system_graph/) というソフトがあるそうなので試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

[GPUのメモリ使用率の確認方法（Windows） - Qiita](https://qiita.com/samacoba/items/368d67f2d7d4e11abdf7)